# t450s Broadwell Linux system hangs repeatedly in X11

Tags: linux, xorg, freeze, thinkpad

I've got a Thinkpad t450s with integrated Broadwell Intel graphics. For quite a while now, the system has been hanging in graphical mode. This has happened across major kernel versions (3.x -> 4.x), kernel minor versions (e.g. 4.8.0 to 4.8.11, and multiple versions of the X.org server (1.16, 1.17) as well.

The symptoms are that the system becomes almost completely unresponsive. I can still toggle keyboard LEDs, but otherwise the system is unresponsive. I cannot ctrl-alt-del, I cannot reach the machine via the network (and any existing network connections fail). There are no log entries, there's no trace that it happened.

I'm not sure where to turn to troubleshoot this. My X11 configuration is default, it happens across window managers, it happens regardless of which applications I'm running. How do I troubleshoot this? Where should I look for possible culprits? Is my best bet setting up remote kernel debugging?

Comment: I'd start with ``/var/log/messages`` (or ``journalctl``if you use it ``journald``)

Comment: I specified in my question that there's nothing in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

`touch /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` Fill it with following content.

`Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection`

This change the acceleration from sna to uxa. Reboot.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I didn't receive a notification for this answer (I swear I turned them on!). Do you have any links or anything I can read to learn about how this would address the problem I'm seeing? I'm doing some searches myself and not finding anything. I'll definitely give it a shot and will report back about how it went. Thank you!

Comment: This definitely seems to have fixed things. I've been using the system for several days now and have not had any problems at all. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sadly, a few hours after I accepted this answer, the problem manifested again. :( The hunt continues.

Comment: Have you .xsession-errors or .xsession-errors.old file in your $HOME?